# NSMeasurementFormatter shows Imperial weights but not metric weights?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsmeasurementformatter

I have implemented an NSMeasurementFormatter and am having an odd issue. When the app is loaded as en_US, I get all my weights loaded into the text boxes as pounds, brilliant. However when I switch my app to en_GB and load the same data, i get nothing appearing in the text boxes.

When i print the objects the print out states the weights in kg so they are converting correctly, but they arent loading into the actual text boxes to be visible to the user.

Is there any clear cause to this? I have spent a few hours trying to work out why it works for one location but not the other! Appreciate the insight, here is the code:

Here is the initial save of an exercise where it either goes one way ot another depending on the apps setup at this point

```
        if self.localeIdentifier == "en_GB" {
            let kgWeight = Measurement(value: Double(self.userExerciseWeight.text!)!, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)
            newUserExercise.weight = kgWeight as NSObject?
            newUserExercise.initialMetricSystem = self.localeIdentifier
            print("SAVED AS \(localeIdentifier) METRIC")
        } else if self.localeIdentifier == "en_US" {
            let lbsWeight = Measurement(value: Double(self.userExerciseWeight.text!)!, unit: UnitMass.pounds)
            newUserExercise.weight = lbsWeight as NSObject?
            newUserExercise.initialMetricSystem = self.localeIdentifier
            print("SAVED AS \(localeIdentifier) IMPERIAL")
        }
```

Then here is my attempt to later reload this objects weight property

```
   let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
    let exerciseWeight = userExercise.weight as! Measurement<Unit>
    let localeIdentifier = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "locale")
    let locale = Locale(identifier: localeIdentifier as! String)
    formatter.locale = locale
    let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
    formatter.numberFormatter = numberFormatter

    let finalWeight = formatter.string(from: exerciseWeight)
    cell.todaysExerciseWeightLabel.text = finalWeight 
}
```

So when set to US, i get a pounds readout to 2 decimal places, but when i set to GB i get nothing visible, i can just see it did the conversion in the print out of the object, pics below of the console that shows for loading both routines, and shots of the results:

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATED BELOW WITH MASSFORMATTER INFO**

```
    let localeIdentifier = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "locale") as! Locale
    let exerciseWeight = userExercise.weight as! Measurement<Unit>
    let formatter = MassFormatter()
    formatter.numberFormatter.locale = localeIdentifier
    formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

    if localeIdentifier.usesMetricSystem {
        let kgWeight = exerciseWeight.converted(to: .kilograms)
        let finalKgWeight = formatter.string(fromValue: kgWeight.value, unit: .kilogram)
        cell.todaysExerciseWeightLabel.text = finalKgWeight
        print(formatter.string(fromValue: kgWeight.value, unit: .kilogram))
    } else {
        let kgWeight = exerciseWeight.converted(to: .pounds)
        let finalLbWeight = formatter.string(fromValue: exerciseWeight.value, unit: .pound)
        cell.todaysExerciseWeightLabel.text = finalLbWeight
        print(formatter.string(fromValue: exerciseWeight.value, unit: .pound))
    }
}
```

}

Comment: This is easily reproducible and it seems to be a bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It all boils down to the following piece of code:

```
let weight = Measurement(value: 10.0, unit: UnitMass.kilograms)

let formatter = MeasurementFormatter()
formatter.locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")

print(formatter.string(from: weight))
```

The result is an empty `String` (`""`). 
This is an obvious bug. Please, report it.

A simple workaround is using the older `MassFormatter`:

```
//let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_GB")
let locale = Locale(identifier: "en_US")

let weight = Measurement(value: 10.24, unit: UnitMass.pounds)

let formatter = MassFormatter()
formatter.numberFormatter.locale = locale
formatter.numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2

if locale.usesMetricSystem {
    let kgWeight = weight.converted(to: .kilograms)
    print(formatter.string(fromValue: kgWeight.value, unit: .kilogram))
} else {
    print(formatter.string(fromValue: weight.value, unit: .pound))
}
```

Comment: sorry to be a noob but how do i report things? Does this mean i cant finish this part of my app now? It seems odd that it works with en_US but not en_GB

Comment: The string although it doesnt print, loads a value when using en_US, just not with en_GB, they both print empty but one still works...

Comment: Thanks for adding the mass formatter code, im having some issues with it saying that 'Unit' is not a subtype of 'Dimensions' on the let kgWeight lines. What has i got wrong here? Added code to the OP. I presume i need to edit my exercise.weight objects when they save now to conform to a mass rather than measurement setup?

Comment: @jwarris91 Replace `as! Measurement<Unit>` with `as! Measurement<UnitMass>`.

Comment: Thanks that seems to be working now, i reported the massformatter bug too

Comment: An additional query if you have time, is there a way to prevent the 'kg' loading alongside the number? for example here...                let finalKgWeight = formatter.string(fromValue: kgWeight.value, unit: .kilogram) and then setting userExerciseWeight.text = finalKgWeight will show "150 kg" in the text box, however my exercise builder only accepts integers so the 'kg' part crashes the app, i want it to just load the 150 part

Comment: @jwarris91 If you don't want the units displayed, then use a simple `NumberFormatter` and not a `MassFormatter`...

Comment: thanks ill give it a go, its just in 1 instance where the user edits the object, its loading the units in after the number which causes a crash when its looking for an Integer, the Massformatter is fine in all other circumstances when its displaying uneditable data

Comment: In theory i still need the mass formatter? as I may need to convert the metric between lb or kg, just only display the numbers?